# Python counter not recognizing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list and a dictionary and I want to ultimately find a sum of the values in the two. For example, I want the code below to return :

```
{gold coin : 45, rope : 1, dagger : 6, ruby : 1}
```

First I right a function to turn the dragonLoot list into a dictionary and then I run a Counter to add the two dictionaries together. However, when I run the code I get the following:

```
{'ruby': 1, 'gold coin': 3, 'dagger': 1}
Counter({'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 5, 'rope': 1})
```

For some reason it looks like the Counter is not recognizing the dictionary that I create from dragonLoot. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
inv = {'gold coin' : 42, 'rope' : 1, 'dagger' : 5}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby']

def inventory(item):
    count = {}
    for x in range(len(item)):
        count.setdefault(item[x],0)
        count[item[x]] = count[item[x]] + 1
    print(count)

inv2 = inventory(dragonLoot)

from collections import Counter
dicts = [inv,inv2]
c = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    c.update(d)

print(c)
```

Comment: Why not set `count` to `inv` inside inventory? avoid this counter altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the count in your inventory method:

```
def inventory(item):
    count = {}
    for x in range(len(item)):
        count.setdefault(item[x],0)
        count[item[x]] = count[item[x]] + 1
    print(count)
```

You are simply printing your inventory calculation. Change that print to a return, or add a return line after the print:

```
def inventory(item):
    count = {}
    for x in range(len(item)):
        count.setdefault(item[x],0)
        count[item[x]] = count[item[x]] + 1
    print(count)
    return count
```

Adding that to your code and running it, gives this output:

```
Counter({'gold coin': 45, 'dagger': 6, 'rope': 1, 'ruby': 1})
```

Alternatively, the implementation provided by @nneonneo is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `inventory` function: `Counter` will count the iterable for you. You can also use `+` with `Counter`. Combine these, and you can do quite simply

```
inv = Counter({'gold coin' : 42, 'rope' : 1, 'dagger' : 5})
dragonLoot = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby']

inv += Counter(dragonLoot)
```

After this is run, `inv` will be `Counter({'gold coin': 45, 'dagger': 6, 'rope': 1, 'ruby': 1})`, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way to do it without the `Counter`:

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby']
inv = {'gold coin' : 42, 'rope' : 1, 'dagger' : 5}
for i in dragonLoot:
    inv[i] = inv.get(i, 0) +1
print (inv)
```

Output:

```
{'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 6, 'ruby': 1}
```